# Avoiding redundancy in database tables sql mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question please.

I am developing an online mall website.

I have an orders table.. I have put the product_id as an attribute in order to know which product is ordered.

In the customer's purchase history page, I need to present all the orders purchased by the customer, including the product title and product image which are not included in the orders table.. In order to get them we can select and join order table and products table.

But what if the store owner deleted the product from the products table after a certain time, and I want to still present the product's title or image in the purchase history page.. What can I do?

If the solution is to repeat them as attributes in the orders table.. **Isn't it considered as redundancy**?

Comment: Never delete products, just mark them as "not sold anymore".

Comment: don't let them delete a product only mark it as delete,  so that it will not be displayed anymore

Comment: doesn't this keep a huge number of products in the database for a long time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is virtual deletes.

In the products table, add a `IsDeleted` or perhaps `Active` column with a default value. If the store owner "deletes" a product, flip the flag to it's opposing value. This retains the data on the product without stopping store owners from trimming products, and also allows for the easy reinstatement of a product.

Queries will need to be tweaked to account for the flag, but that's a small price to pay for data integrity.

Comment: doesn't this keep a huge number of products in the database for a long time?

Comment: No, actually. It keeps _all_ of the products in the database _forever_. What's a "huge number"? I used to work for a Fortune 500 retailer that has been in business for decades and the product table was just a few million rows.

Comment: Side benefit: On the customer's history page, you could leverage the flag to show a "no longer available" marker to save them the trouble of trying to find something that they can't re-order. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. And well done, thinking through the data model in the construction phase.

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind ..

as i said i need to make purchase history that contains details about order made by the customer. ( such as : order number, payment paid, product name, product picture, etc..)

What if a customer made an order and these details were saved in the purchase history, and then the store owner for a reason changed (updated) the product's name => then this update will appear in the purchase history.. is it true that this must not happen?

Comment: let's assume a customer bought product named (Men blue shoes) and then after a month the store owner updated the product name into (Men black shoes) .. and this update will appear in the purchase history which is a wrong information.
What can we do in this approach?

Comment: Of course taking into consideration that we are avoiding repeating attributes.
We don't want to make a table name purchase history that has all the attributes of the product repeated. True?

Comment: Well, now what you’re talking about would mean, in Kimball model terms, implementing a slowly changing dimension. Tricky to maintain, but worth your time to research.